# Interfacing TinyAVR with bluetooth and passing message

Tags: bluetooth, interface, attiny

I'm looking into interfacing the [TinyAVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/tinyavr.aspx) micro controller (not sure which one will work yet) with a Bluetooth module either the [CC2540](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2540&DCMP=LowPowerRFICs+Other&HQS=Other+OT+cc2540) or the [nRF8001](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001). I want to have the TinyAVR micro controller use the Bluetooth module to send out a small message like 0xf for example, which my computer would then read and display on screen.

My goal is to see if I can make kinda a hardware echo. Is it possible to interface these two units? If they can be interfaced what is required to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting the two will be possible but those are both chipset level solutions and will require significant expertise in PCB design and firmware programming. Without sounding condescending it sounds like a beginner question so although they are more expensive you'd probably be better of with a module that offers a simple serial interface and won't require any PCB design.

An example of such a module is the [RN42-XV Bluetooth Module from Sparkfun](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/11601), I just picked that out as a quick example of one that is reasonably priced and should be easy to use. They and other suppliers have many modules along similar lines. For those you can connect using a UART and send serial commands to setup connections much like you'd do with a modem.

Another solution may be an [Arduino BT](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth) board, I've never used one but Arduino boards typically have lots of example code to help you get started quickly.

Comment: might I ask would it be possible to do with just the Bluetooth SoC and completely remove the TinyAVR chip from the equation?

Comment: @TaylorBioniks, the CC2540 has an inbuilt 8051 processor so the TinyAVR wouldn't be required for that. They also have a development kit that looks good if you don't mind shelling out $299. Actually for RF development it's always good to have a known working test system to start with even when you've done it before.

Comment: one final question if I may?
would I be able to make a lead brink off of just the CC2540 or the nRF8001?

Comment: @TaylorBioniks, the CC2540 certainly could, most I/O ports have 4mA drive but there's a couple of 20mA as well if you wanted something brighter.